# using "greater than or equal" operator in linq join operation

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

i wonder if it is possible to use "greater than or equal" and "less than" operators in join operation of linq2sql ?

i have a t-sql query as follows..

```
SELECT  R.firstRange,
        R.lastRange, 
        COUNT(1) AS quantity
FROM   product L
JOIN   priceRanges R ON L.salePrice >= R.firstRange AND L.salePrice < R.lastRange 
GROUP  BY R.firstRange,R.lastRange;
```

can i get same result depends on two DataTable (product and priceRanges) with linq ?

Thanks in advance..